# Deeply complicated JPA mapping producing tables with NULL values

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below are the entities (assume getters and setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report_yearly")
public class AnalyticsReportYearly
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long reportId;
    
    private long viewId;
    private long startYear;
    private long endYear;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_id", referencedColumnName = "dataId")
    private AnalyticsData data;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="column_header_id", referencedColumnName = "columnHeaderId")
    private AnalyticsColumnHeader columnHeader;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="report_monthly")
public class AnalyticsReportMonthly
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long reportId;
    
    private long viewId;
    private long startYear;
    private long startMonth;
    private long endYear;
    private long endMonth;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_id", referencedColumnName = "dataId")
    private AnalyticsData data;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="column_header_id", referencedColumnName = "columnHeaderId")
    private AnalyticsColumnHeader columnHeader;
}
```

Above are the two top level entities. Either yearly or monthly reports are generated.
Below are the further nestings :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report_data")
public class AnalyticsData
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dataId;
    
    @JsonProperty
    private boolean isDataGolden;
    
    private long rowCount;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "maximums",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsValue> maximums = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "minimums",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsValue> minimums = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "totals",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsValue> totals = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "analyticsData",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="data")
    private AnalyticsReportMonthly analyticsReportMonthly;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="data")
    private AnalyticsReportYearly analyticsReportYearly;

    getIsDataGolden() ; setIsDataGolden()
}


@Entity
@Table(name="report_column_header")
public class AnalyticsColumnHeader
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long columnHeaderId;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="column_header_dimensions",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="column_header_id"))
    @Column(name="header_dimension")
    private List<String> dimensions = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "metric_header_id", referencedColumnName = "metricHeaderId")
    private AnalyticsMetricHeader metricHeader;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "columnHeader")
    private AnalyticsReportYearly analyticsReportYearly;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "columnHeader")
    private AnalyticsReportMonthly analyticsReportMonthly;
}
```

Below are the further nested entities for AnalyticsData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report_data_values")
public class AnalyticsValue
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long valueId;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="data_values",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="data_value_id"))
    @Column(name="data_value")
    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_maximums_id")
    private AnalyticsData maximums;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_minimums_id")
    private AnalyticsData minimums;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_totals_id")
    private AnalyticsData totals;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="row_id")
    private AnalyticsRow analyticsRow;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="report_row")
public class AnalyticsRow
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long rowId;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="row_dimensions",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="row_id"))
    @Column(name="row_dimension")
    private List<String> dimensions = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "analyticsRow",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsValue> metrics = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_id")
    private AnalyticsData analyticsData;
}
```

Below the nesting for AnalyticsColumnHeader :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report_metric_header")
public class AnalyticsMetricHeader
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long metricHeaderId;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "analyticsMetricHeader",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AnalyticsMetricHeaderEntry> metricHeaderEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "metricHeader")
    private AnalyticsColumnHeader analyticsColumnHeader;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="report_metric_header_entry")
public class AnalyticsMetricHeaderEntry
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long metricHeaderEntryId;
    
    private String name;
    private String type;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="METRIC_HEADER_ID")
    private AnalyticsMetricHeader analyticsMetricHeader;
}
```

All of the tables have data except 'report_data_values'(Entity:AnalyticsValue), where it has the value_id auto-generated values. But row_id,data_maximums_id,data_minimums_id,data_totals_id are all NULL.

Below is the JSON that I am supposed to store :

```
        {
            "columnHeader": {
                "dimensions": [
                    "ga:userAgeBracket"
                ],
                "metricHeader": {
                    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                        {
                            "name": "Users",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "New Users",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Page Views",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sessions",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Average Session Duration",
                            "type": "TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Bounce Rate",
                            "type": "PERCENT"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "isDataGolden": true,
                "maximums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "1864099",
                            "594855",
                            "13718093",
                            "6622035",
                            "228.37076740102023",
                            "75.14374842506706"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "minimums": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "297293",
                            "97265",
                            "2945414",
                            "1076230",
                            "110.43645338547087",
                            "58.1395240794254"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "rowCount": 6,
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "18-24"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "899425",
                                    "441934",
                                    "3560704",
                                    "2008022",
                                    "110.43645338547087",
                                    "75.14374842506706"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "25-34"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1864099",
                                    "594855",
                                    "12278420",
                                    "6622035",
                                    "133.32916150397875",
                                    "73.01240479701482"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "35-44"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1465642",
                                    "411498",
                                    "13718093",
                                    "6213080",
                                    "173.1176128425837",
                                    "65.26962472718844"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "45-54"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "1210565",
                                    "310384",
                                    "10417304",
                                    "5046694",
                                    "161.0130176309481",
                                    "68.25864615528502"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "55-64"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "598618",
                                    "191724",
                                    "4071168",
                                    "1920737",
                                    "162.661150381338",
                                    "67.63612092649852"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "65+"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "297293",
                                    "97265",
                                    "2945414",
                                    "1076230",
                                    "228.37076740102023",
                                    "58.1395240794254"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "totals": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            "6335642",
                            "2047660",
                            "46991103",
                            "22886798",
                            "155.15735189343656",
                            "68.89865502373901"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

These are the relevant details.
Note : I have been getting '415 Unsupported Media Type' because I added '@JsonManagedReference' and '@JsonBackReference'. I have added those because for a previous project I couldn't retrieve the JSON from the front end.

But now I am just trying to send the above JSON, so I could remove those annotations. Before adding those annotations, it saved successfully but I the values are NULL as I mentioned above.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the JsonBackReferences set in your AnalyticsData instances when you deserialize from JSON? Them being null is why null gets inserted for those foreign keys - you'll have to set them if you are going to have JSON manage serialization in this way, or switch possibly to using JsonIdentityInfo instead.

Comment: @Chris - I have never used JsonIdentityInfo. Can you be more specific where to put it ? Thanks